# RxJava - how to see Flowable and backpressure in action?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I am writing a sample app, that processes the bitmap. The process can be controlled by a slider, so when the slider position is changed, I generate another bitmap.

When the user drags the slider, it emits some 10-20 events per second. Processing the bitmap takes about 1 second, so the processing queue becomes quickly stuck with requests.

It seems like a good backpressure example to me, but I couldn't figure out how to use stuff like `Flowable` and `BackpressureStrategy` to handle it properly.  Moreover, I couldn't make this small sample work:

```
val pubsub = PublishSubject.create<Int>()

pubsub
.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
.observeOn(computation())
.subscribe {
      Timber.d("consume %d - %s", it, Thread.currentThread().name)
      Thread.sleep(3000)
}

for (i in 0 .. 1000) {
      Timber.d("emit %d - %s", i, Thread.currentThread().name)
      pubsub.onNext(i)
}
```

Well, I expect this code to emit 1000 integers through `PublishSubject`, but as long as processing each takes 3 seconds, 999 of integers should be dropped, only "0" and "1000" should be processed...

But in the logs I see, that all my integers are slowly processed, one by one, and the backpressure strategy is ignored. Actually, `toFlowable(...)` expression seems to do nothing. With or without backpressure, I see 1000 emissions followed by the several minutes of consumption.

What am I missing here? How can I drop the intermediate elements and consume only the latest available?

**solved**:

`observeOn(computation())` is actually `observeOn(computation(), delayErrors = false, bufferSize = 128)`. To see real backpressure, decrease the bufferSize, when you call `observeOn(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be related to `observeOn(computation())`. Depending on the backing thread, this might be throttled automatically. The emission of the items is queued. Therefore there's no backpressure on the `Flowable`.

Try putting these thread changes before `toFlowable(LATEST)` or use a different `Scheduler` which is not as forgiving or put even more items to `pubsub`.

Also you could use [`observeOn(Scheduler scheduler, boolean, int)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#observeOn-io.reactivex.Scheduler-boolean-int-) to enforce a bufferSize.

Comment: Thank you! Looks like observeOn(scheduler) is actually the same thing as observeOn(scheduler, bufferSize = 128), so actual backpressure would occur only at 129-th element. I've never waited long enough to see 128 elements consumed.